# Is it possible to detect whether object is a temporary from within member function?

Tags: c++, rvalue, temporary-objects

I'm implementing a decorator pattern on immutable objects with the pointer-to-implementation idiom. Basically my setup looks like this

```
struct Object : ObjectBase {
     void doSmth() override {
         impl->doSmth();
     }
     // this is the function I'd like to implement
     Object decorateWith(std::unique_ptr<ObjectDecorator>&&);
private:
     std::unique_ptr<ObjectBase> impl;
};

struct ObjectDecorator : ObjectBase {
    void doSmth() override {
        // do some stuff
        impl->doSmth();
        // do some more stuff
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<ObjectBase> impl;
};
```

Here, the decorateWith function is supposed to have different behavior depending on the whether the object it is callen on is a temporary or not. If it is called on a non-temporary object, it is supposed to return a new Object instance where I have to make a deep copy of the current Object and store it in the  unique_ptr of the decorator while the impl pointer of the new Object itself is pointing to the decorator.
If, however, decorateWith is called on a temporary, it suffices to create a ObjectDecorator and just move the impl-pointer of the current object into the impl pointer of the decorator and let the object point to the new decorator.

In order to impelement that I need a way to determine from within the call to decorateWith whether the object is a temporary or not and then use tag-dispatch based on the result of that check. Is that possible?

Best
Xodion

EDIT: Sample caller code could look like this:

- decorateWith is called on a non-temporary

  ```
  int main() {
      Object x{};

      // this call does not modify x so it can be reused later
      Object y = x.decorateWith{std::make_unique<ObjectDecorator>()};
      y.doSmth();

      // do some other stuff here

      // here, if I had moved the impl-unique_ptr in the decorateWith
      // call this would now segfault since I'd call nullptr->doSmth();
      x.doSmth();

  }
  ```
- decorateWith is called on a temporary

  ```
  int main() {
      Object x = Object{}.decorateWith(std::make_unique<ObjectDecorator>())
                         .decorateWith(std::make_unique<ObjectDecorator>())
                         .decorateWith(std::make_unique<ObjectDecorator>());
       // in this case it would be unneccessary to make a deep copy of all
       // previous instances so I'd like to only move the impl poiner every time
       x.doSmth()
   }
  ```

Comment: Your explanation might be better backed up with sample calling code.

Comment: Are you asking to determine whether the `Object` `decorateWith` is called from is temporary, or if the argument to `decorateWith` is temporary?

Comment: I want to conditionally move only when the object on which decorateWith is called on is a temporary and make a deep copy otherwise, so it is about how to check whether an object is temporary.  As the answers below illustrate there is no need for some kind of type trait since one can overload using ref-qualifiers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have ref-qualifiers on member functions. Copied example from [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions)

```
#include <iostream>
struct S {
    void f() & { std::cout << "lvalue\n"; }
    void f() &&{ std::cout << "rvalue\n"; }
};

int main(){
    S s;
    s.f();            // prints "lvalue"
    std::move(s).f(); // prints "rvalue"
    S().f();          // prints "rvalue"
}
```

So in your situation, you would want to have something like this

```
 Object decorateWith(std::unique_ptr<ObjectDecorator>&&) &;
 Object decorateWith(std::unique_ptr<ObjectDecorator>&&) &&;
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, but nevertheless the ref-qualifiers are what I need.

Answer (score 4):

You can use reference qualifiers to overload the member function similar to the way you'd use `const` to overload for `const` and non-`const` objects:

```
Object decorateWith(std::unique_ptr<ObjectDecorator>&&) const&
{
    // implementation if this is not a temporary
}

Object decorateWith(std::unique_ptr<ObjectDecorator>&&) &&
{
    // implementation if this IS a temporary
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If you implement the following two methods:

```
 Object decorateWith(std::unique_ptr<ObjectDecorator>&&) &;
 Object decorateWith(std::unique_ptr<ObjectDecorator>&&) &&;
```

the second will be called if `*this` is an rvalue.